# ASP.NET MVC & Ajax json Datatables errors - json error, cells not displaying data

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

This may be a duplicate but I've tried everything I can find on stack exchange and datatables.net forums. I can't get it to work at all.

I have `var listOfFiles` which is a list of the following model (`List<AudioModel>`):

```
public class AudioModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public bool Select { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAudio()
{
    var listOfFiles = asa.GetAudioFilesFromServer(serverpath);
    return Json(new { data = listOfFiles }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Console output from chrome -

[image]

View -

```
    <table class="display compact table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="audiotable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Album</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>FilePath</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetAudio", "Music")"
    })

    // screenshot of this above
    console.log(jsonData);

    $("#audiotable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "type": "GET",
            "contentType": "json",
            "data": jsonData,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id" },
                { "data": "Title" },
                { "data": "Artist" },
                { "data": "Album" },
                { "data": "Duration" },
                { "data": "Select" },
                { "data": "FilePath" }
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

with the above code I get DataTables error 1.
[image]I've tried         `jsonData.responseJSON`

I get DataTables error 4 when I serialize json but I understand that with the above code I need a json array, not a string.

I've closely followed the troubleshooting for both errors. my json looks perfect, is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please try this, change   return Json(new { data = listOfFiles }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   to   return Json( listOfFiles , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is getting your jsondata using ajax then passing the data to ajax call of datatables init. That's not going to work. You don't need your ajax  call outside of datatables.

Try this:

```
$("#audiotable").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url: "@Url.Action("GetAudio", "Music")"
        type: "GET"
    }, 

    "columns": [
            { "data": "Id" },
            { "data": "Title" },
            { "data": "Artist" },
            { "data": "Album" },
            { "data": "Duration" },
            { "data": "Select" },
            { "data": "FilePath" }
        ]
});
```

Update your action to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAudio()
{
    var listOfFiles = asa.GetAudioFilesFromServer(serverpath);
    return Json(listOfFiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have tried that previously and I've attempted again I get an empty table with no error

Answer (score 0):

You can move AJAX call inside init DataTable like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#audiotable').DataTable({
                "ajax": "/Music/GetAudio",
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Title" },
                    { "data": "Artist" },
                    { "data": "Album" },
                    { "data": "Duration" }
                ]
            });
    });
```